# Convert sparse pandas dataframe with `NaN` into integer values

Tags: python, pandas, binary, int

I have a binary pandas dataframe with values `0.0`, `1.0`, and `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

I would like to turn the floats `1.0` and `0.0` into integers `1` and `0`. Unfortunately, because of `NaN` value, this command fails:

```
df.applymap(int)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: ('cannot convert float NaN to integer', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Are there "pandas" alternatives?

Comment: What do you want the integer value of `NaN` to be?   What should be the output for input of `0.0, 1.0, NaN`?

Comment: @recursive I want `1.0` to be `1`, `0.0` to be `0` and `NaN` to be ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

if you need nice looking **string** values you can do it:

```
In [84]: df.astype(object)
Out[84]:
   a  b    c
0  0  1    0
1  0  0    1
2  1  1    1
3  0  1    1
4  1  1  NaN
```

but all values - are strings (`object` in pandas terms):

```
In [85]: df.astype(object).dtypes
Out[85]:
a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object
```

Timings against 500K rows DF:

```
In [86]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [87]: df.shape
Out[87]: (500000, 3)

In [88]: %timeit df.astype(object)
10 loops, best of 3: 113 ms per loop

In [89]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x).astype(object)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.86 s per loop
```

**OLD answer:**

AFAIK you can't do it using modern pandas versions.

Here is a demo:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  0.0
1  NaN  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0  NaN

In [53]: df[pd.isnull(df)] = -1

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
     a    b    c
0  1.0 -1.0  0.0
1 -1.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0 -1.0

In [55]: df = df.astype(int)

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
   a  b  c
0  1 -1  0
1 -1  1  1
2  0  0 -1
```

we are almost there, let's replace `-1` with `NaN`:

```
In [57]: df[df < 0] = np.nan

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  0.0
1  NaN  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0  NaN
```

Another demo:

```
In [60]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  1
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
```

look what happens with `c` column if we change a single cell in it to `NaN`:

```
In [62]: df.loc[4, 'c'] = np.nan

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
   a  b    c
0  1  0  0.0
1  1  0  1.0
2  0  1  1.0
3  0  0  1.0
4  0  0  NaN
```

Comment: The best answer appears to be `df.astype(object)`.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, so you don't need `integer values` as your subject states? Do you need strings that look like integers?

Comment: Actually, that didn't work either...whenever I save the matrix via `df.to_cvs()`, it saves the integers as floats.....Any other ideas what to do?

Answer (score 3):

As of pandas 0.24 (January 2019), you can achieve what you need without resolving to `object`, by using [nullable integers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#integer-na) instead. Using @MaxU's example:

```
In [125]: df
Out[125]:
   a  b    c
0  0  1  0.0
1  0  0  1.0
2  1  1  1.0
3  0  1  1.0
4  1  1  NaN

In [126]: df.astype('Int64')
Out[126]:
   a  b    c
0  0  1    0
1  0  0    1
2  1  1    1
3  0  1    1
4  1  1  NaN
```